# How to add and show an Open file dialog and Save file dialog in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, filedialog

How do I insert an OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog control in MS-Access '07? Also, how do I code it in VBA so as to display it?

Thanks,

S Sandeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access 2007 you should be able to use the `.FileDialog` method as explained in the following Microsoft Knowledge Base article:

[How to display and to use the File dialog box in Microsoft Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824272)